# 'Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found' When iterating through a loop reading a file

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, nosuchelementexception

Java noob here. So I'm writing a program that reads data from a text file, and stores the data into an array of objects. Each iteration of the loops reads 4 pieces of data (a name (string), and 3 corresponding numbers (doubles)). It then creates an object that calls a constructor, and stores an object in each element of an array. There are 10 separate items, so there 40 lines in the text file.

For some reason my loop is correctly reading the first 9 items (or 36 lines), but it won't read the last 4 lines. I've written a print statement within the loop to see whats going on and that's what it looks like. I've also tried both a for loop and a while loop. Here is the method I'm writing:

```
    public static PlanetData[] readFile() throws IOException
    {
        String name;
        double radius, flux, distance;

        final int ARRAY_SIZE = 10;
        PlanetData[] planArray = new PlanetData[ARRAY_SIZE];

        File planetFile = new File("PlanetData.txt");
        Scanner planetFileInput = new Scanner(planetFile);

        int index = 0;
        while(planetFileInput.hasNext() && index < planArray.length)
        {
            name     = planetFileInput.nextLine();
            radius   = planetFileInput.nextDouble();
            flux     = planetFileInput.nextDouble();
            distance = planetFileInput.nextDouble();
            planetFileInput.nextLine();

            System.out.println(index + ":  " + name + " " + radius + " " + flux + " " + distance);

            planArray[index] = new PlanetData(name, radius, flux, distance);

            index++;
        }



        return planArray;
```

I'm getting the following errors:

```
0:  Proxima Cen b, 1.1, 0.66, 4.2
1:  Kapteyn b*,    1.6, 0.43, 13.0
2:  GJ 667 C c,    1.5, 0.88, 22.0
3:  GJ 667 C f*,   1.4, 0.56, 22.0
4:  TRAPPIST-1 e,  0.9, 0.65, 39.0
5:  TRAPPIST-1 f,  1.0, 0.38, 39.0
6:  LHS 1140 b,    1.4, 0.41, 41.0
7:  Kepler-1229 b, 1.4, 0.49, 769.0
8:  Kepler-442 b,  1.3, 0.7,  1115.0

Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
    at PlanetClient.readFile(PlanetClient.java:57)
    at PlanetClient.main(PlanetClient.java:13)
```

Edit: And here is the data in the text file:

```
Proxima Cen b
1.1
0.66
4.2
Kapteyn b*
1.6
0.43
13
GJ 667 C c
1.5
0.88
22
GJ 667 C f*
1.4
0.56
22
TRAPPIST-1 e
0.9
0.65
39
TRAPPIST-1 f
1
0.38
39
LHS 1140 b
1.4
0.41
41
Kepler-1229 b
1.4
0.49
769
Kepler-442 b
1.3
0.7
1115
Kepler-62 f
1.4
0.39
1200
```

Comment: It could just be that the last line in your file does not end with a newline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the 8th entry the last entry in your PlanetData.txt? It looks like you are calling next line when setting the name of the first entry, and then again at the end of the conditional. It seems as if this would cause your code to skip every other entry, and then try to read the line after the last. Could you post the data in PlanetData.txt? Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your help! So the 8th entry (or 9th item) is the second to last entry in the text file. There are 4 more lines (so one item/object) left in the text file that the code is not reading. Could you explain what you mean by "you are calling next line when setting the name of the first entry"? Sorry I'm still quite a noob with java. I will try and edit the original post with the full text file too, sorry about that! Thanks again,

Comment: Sure, when the line "name     = planetFileInput.nextLine();" executes, it causes your scanner to literally go to the next line. You then read in various values and AGAIN call "planetFileInput.nextLine();" which causes your scanner object to once again go to the next line. This is resulting in a line being skipped every iteration, and thus, at the end you try to read a line that isn't there. You could theoretically add an extra line to your text file and this error would go away... but you would still have a big issue with the integrity of your planet data.

Comment: Oh wow, so yea adding a new line at the end of the text file solves the problem! I didn't realize the name assignment causes it to go to the next line but that makes sense. So with the extra line it appears everything works, all the data is correct. 
But is there any way to solve this without editing the text file? Theoretically I'd like to not have to ever open or edit it but I can't figure out how to properly read everything without doing that. Thank you again for the help!

Comment: It really depends on how you have your data stored. Based on your description, you have cross line related values. If all the data being returned is truly correct, then you might consider adding "if(!planetFileInput.hasNextLine()){break;}"  right before you call "planetFileInput.nextLine();".

Comment: Hi, if this helped you, could you please select it as the answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry about that! Forgot about this thread. This worked perfectly, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You are reading a line with 'planetFileInput.nextLine()' twice and not doing any thing with the second time result.
Remove the second occurrence.

Generally, you shuold have one nextLine() invocation for every hasNext() invocation.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. There is a newline after the third double, and the `nextLine()` consumes that. If the OP removes that, then the next `nextLine()` will consume this empty string, instead of the next planet name. The last line probably doesn't have anything - not even a newline - following the last double.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Could you explain what you mean by reading it twice? There is the 'planetFileInput.nextLine()' after all the doubles, but where is the second occurrence that you mention? Sorry like I said I'm very much a noob with java. Also, when I remove that nextLine() call, it only reads the first 4 entries and a mismatch error occurs.